# Confusion with attenuator noise

Tags: power, noise, thermal, attenuator

I am a little confused as to what happens to the input thermal noise value as it passes through an attenuator.

As I understand if you have a signal of 10dB and passes it through a 6dB attenuator it will reduce to 4dB. But for a noise of 10dB there is an added noise coming the attenuator itself, but is the overall output noise just equal to \$N_{0} = k_{B}TB\$.

Also if the input thermal noise is coming from a 300K temperature and moving to an attenuator at a lower temperature e.g 50K, how is equation affected?

Comment: Treat noise just as you would a signal. If it's 10 dBm (the m bit means milliwatts) then the noise on the output due only from attenuation is 4 dBm. You add that vectorially to the inherent output noise of the output impedance.

Comment: The noise at the output of the attenuator will be the input thermal noise reduced by 6 dB, plus the thermal noise of the attenuator itself.

Comment: If the input noise stays the same (the 300 deg K source you referenced), but if you lower the temperature of the attenuator, the noise contribution of the attenuator itself is reduced but the noise from the input source remains the same.  This is the principal behind cooling the front end (LNAs) of radio telescopes to low temperatures.

Comment: So if the attenuator is at a different temperature what is thermal noise which is added? And also why is the input noise not attenuated at different temperature?

Comment: @AttenuatorMan - You basically have two different noise sources, at two different temperatures.  The input noise is attenuated by the loss (attenuation) of the attenuator itself which, for a well designed attenuator, is fairly constant across temperature.  While the noise from the attenuator is dependent upon its temperature.

Answer (score 1):

If the attenuator is at a low temperature (50K) the added thermal noise is lower. It is "kb Tatt B"  where "Tatt"  is the attenuator temperature = 50K.

A lot of people are not aware that it is not *only* because a device has a given attenuation that its output noise is fully determinated.

Of course in most situation the device is passive and at 25°C, and in this case its noise contribution is directly deductible from the attenuation.

But, effectively, if a passive attenuator is at a lower temperature, you need to know the temperature to deduce its contribution to noise.

Another case is an active attenuator at ambient temperature. Then it is perfectly possible to have an output noise lower than what it would be for the same passive attenuation (even with ouput impedance matched, 50 Ohms typiccaly).

From all this, the main thing to retain is that all valid explanations that explain the contribution to noise of a attenuator (in particular the famous "noise factor" = "attenuation") should use the hypothesis : passive, at ambient temperature (and maybe impedance matched, but this is another story)